# Marketing Api Permission Exception

Tags: php, facebook, whitelist, facebook-marketing-api

I need to get some automated ad insights using the Marketing Api. For this purpose I have created a System User via the Business Manager, and generated a System User access token with the ads_read permission.

Using this token then to make api calls and get a specific Campaign's Insights, with the FacebookAds php v2.6 sdk, I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\PermissionException'
 with message '(#275) Cannot determine the target object for this
 request. Currently supported objects include ad account, business
 account and associated objects.'
```

Does my app need to be whitelisted or am I missing something else? I noticed that next to the 'ads_read' permission there was this note that stated '(your App must be whitelisted)'.

Here is the sample code I'm using

```
<?php

define('VENDOR_DIR', 'vendor/'); // Path to the Vendor directory 
$loader = require VENDOR_DIR.'autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
// Initialize a new Session and instantiate an Api object
Api::init(
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' // System User Access Token
);

$api = Api::instance();

use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsLevels;

$campaign = new Campaign('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$params = array(
  'level' => InsightsLevels::CAMPAIGN,
);

$async_job = $campaign->getInsightsAsync(array(), $params);

$async_job->read();

while (!$async_job->isComplete()) {
  sleep(1);
  $async_job->read();
}

$async_job->getResult();

?>
```

Comment: seems like the campaign ID that you're trying to use is not valid here

Comment: Thanks for replying @PaulBain! I've used the id that appears after the 'ids' field in the following url. This url is the one I see while viewing my ad. I've also enabled campaign id display using Ads Manager and I can confirm they are the exact number.
busineyadayada/act=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&pid=y&ids=xxxxxxxxx&business_id=yyyy

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app doesn't have ads_read permission. Here you can find more information on how to ask for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access